# Automatically delete GCP Cloud SQL on demand backups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am looking for ways where I can automatically delete Cloud SQL database backups after x number of days. I have found ways to create on demand backup using gcloud command. But does someone know is there a way to automate deletion of on demand backups in GCP CloudSQL?

I have used the below command to create on demand backup is there a flag where i can set number of days to retain this backup?

`gcloud sql backups create \ --async \ --instance=my-instance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that deletes backups for a specific date. It can be modified to run every day and delete X number of days behind.

```
gcloud sql backups list --instance myinstance --sort-by WINDOW_START_TIME --filter 2023-06-06 --format="value(id)" | while read id; do gcloud sql backups delete --instance myinstance $id; done
```

Output:

```
The backup will be deleted. You cannot undo this action.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?
Deleting backup run...
....done.
Deleted backup run [1186013200000].
```

Comment: Thanks alot i have modified a bit and created a bash script to delete the db backup taken x days back.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the accepted answer I have modified the script a little and was able to delete OnDemand/automated backups that was created x days ago.

Use the below shell script to delete any backup that was created 7 days ago

```
#!/bin/bash
current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
new_date=$(date -d "$current_date - 7 days" +%Y-%m-%d)

gcloud sql backups list --instance=my-instance --sort-by WINDOW_START_TIME --filter $new_date | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | while read id; do gcloud sql backups delete --instance=my-instance $id; done
```

**DB instance name is my-instance in this script.**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above answers. I went ahead and modified the script to handle deletion between two given dates.

This works with macOS. You need to readjust for other systems.

```
#!/bin/bash
instance_id=YOUR_INSTANCE_ID
start_date=2021-01-01
end_date=2021-12-31

start_date=$(date -j -f %Y-%m-%d $start_date +%Y-%m-%d)
end_date=$(date -j -f %Y-%m-%d $end_date +%Y-%m-%d)

while [ $start_date != $end_date ]
do
   printf "\033[1;31m-----------------------------------\033[0m\n"
   printf "\033[1;31mDELETING backups from: $start_date!\033[0m\n"

   gcloud sql backups list --instance=$instance_id --sort-by WINDOW_START_TIME --filter $start_date | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | while read id; do gcloud sql backups delete --quiet --instance=$instance_id $id; done

   printf "\033[1;32mDONE $start_date\033[0m!\n"

   start_date=$(date -j -f %Y-%m-%d -v+1d $start_date +%Y-%m-%d)
done
```